# How can you get the isotropic Young's modulus and Poisson's ratio from rheology data?

Tags: biophysics, rheology

I wanted to ask on how to get the Young's modulus and Poisson's ratio for a viscoelastic biomaterial. I have rheological data from the characterization of the biomaterial, the G' and G'' (storage and loss moduli). I also have strain sweep and frequency sweep data.

I am running a finite element simulation in ANSYS, and even if I put the shear rheology data in its properties, it won't run until I put the values of Young's modulus and Poisson's ratio in the isotropic elasticity properties.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You don't show any data, so I'll make some assumptions based on the relations between the linear elasticity moduli shown [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elastic_modulus):

1. The loss modulus $G^{\prime\prime}$ approaches zero as the strain rate or frequency approaches 0, leaving only the storage modulus $G^\prime(0)$.
2. The static shear modulus $G=G^\prime(0)=\frac{3K(1-2\nu)}{2(1+\nu}$ is much less than the bulk modulus $K$ (i.e., $\frac{G}{K}=\frac{3(1-2\nu)}{2(1+\nu}\approx 0$), so Poisson's ratio $\nu$ is approximately 0.5.

Then, estimate static Young's modulus as $E=2G(1+\nu)=3G$.